# Trying to add reply system and get posts in real time on my comment system

Tags: php, mysql

I have been working all week on getting a working comment system on my page, looking around at scripts and trying to learn as much as I can (at one time I was good at this, certified and everything, but I seem to have lost it).

I finally got this to work - it connects to my db not problem and my db accepts data inserted from the form .

However, my issues is that the comments do not show up on my site in real time. Can anyone point me in the right direction to adding this functionality?

My connect.php is as follows:

```
<?php
    $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', '', '', 'london34_db1');

    if(!$connection){
        echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
        echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
        echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
        exit;
    }
```

My commentform.php is as follows:

```
<?php
require('connect.php');

if(isset($_POST) & !empty($_POST)){
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['name']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['email']);
    $subject = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['subject']);

    echo $isql = "INSERT INTO comments (cid, name, email, subject, status) VALUES ('$id', '$name', '$email', '$subject', 'draft')";
    $ires = mysqli_query($connection, $isql) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
    if($ires){
        $smsg = "Your Comment Submitted Successfully";
    }else{
        $fmsg = "Failed to Submit Your Comment";
    }

    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" >

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" >

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-8">

        <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Submit Your Comments</div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <?php if(isset($smsg)){ ?><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"> <?php echo $smsg; ?> </div><?php } ?>
            <?php if(isset($fmsg)){ ?><div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"> <?php echo $fmsg; ?> </div><?php } ?>
            <form method="post">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Name">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Subject</label>
                <textarea name="subject" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Thank you,

Comment: Also I should note that even though my db does receive the comments i get the following text above my form when I post -   INSERT INTO comments (cid, name, email, subject, status) VALUES ('', 'Nick', 'Nick@hotmail.com', 'Testing on June 15', 'draft')

Comment: that's because you echo $isql, see `echo $isql`. Just remove `echo`

Comment: *"comments do not show up on my site in real time"* - Well, where do you show the comments?  Your question seems to be focusing entirely on how you save comments to the DB, which you claim is working.  You're claiming that displaying the comments isn't working, but aren't showing or describing where/how you display them...

Comment: Please be warned that your `INSERT` query is highly vulnerable for SQL injection. Have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

Answer (score 0):

For it to work "real time" you need one of two things.

1. Refresh your page after post (`window.location.reload()`). You could also throw in a name anchor. However, this is outdated, and not recommended.
2. Use AJAX to solve your issue. You have three options, `XMLHttpRequest`, `fetch()`, or if you are using jQuery, `$.ajax()`.

Using ajax should be standard now a days. As it allows for much smoother overall flow of the front end and the back end. You said to have the comments working, so I will continue on that assumption.

Say you have your comment form:

```
<div class="panel-heading">Submit Your Comments</div>
  <!--- code --->
  <form id="comment_form" method="post">
    <!--- more code --->
  </form>
</div>
```

Now let's say when the comment is made, instead of return simple html you return a `json_encoded` object.

Friendly reminder, don't `$_POST` to self. It just mixes things up and makes the waters dirty. We want clean code. Create a file else where with the `POST` handler.

```
<?
if($_POST) {
  // handle the comment $_POST

  // when complete
  if( success ) {
    print_r(json_encode([
      'success' => true,
      'comment_body' => $_POST['comment']
    ]));
  } else {
    print_r(json_encode([
      'success' => false,
      'message' => 'Something went wrong'
    ]));

    exit;
  }
}
```

You can add a simple `fetch()` script to your page:

```
<script>
  var form = document.querySelector('#comment_form'),
      // You need a comment section. Since I didn't see one, I will make my own.
      comment_section = document.querySelector('#comment_section');

  form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    var data = new FormData(form);

    fetch('path/to/your/script.php', {
      body: data,
      method: form.method,
      credentials: 'same-origin'
    })
    .then(response => response.json()) // this is data from the server, you really want the response from your own page. Thus, the second `then` clause.
    .then(data => {
      // right here is where the magic begins
      // lets assume data to be a json object
      if( data.success == true ) {
        // create a new comment element. This is just an example empty div
        var comment = document.createElement('<div>');
        comment.className = "comment new-comment";
        comment.innerHTML = data.comment_body;
        comment_section.appendChild(comment);
      } else {
        // handle a failed comment
      }
    })
    .catch(err => console.warn(err));
  });
</script>
```

Basically what happens here is, user post the comment, you handle it the same way you would.

However, in the response you gather the data submitted to you, then `appendChild` to a comment master div. Which you can set to have the comments by default on there.

This is very basic, and just a proof of concept. Do some more research on it. But I hope this guides you.

Answer (score -1):

PHP is server side, so you would either need to auto refresh the page, or use some Javascript.

To autorefresh:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<?= $seconds?>;URL='<?= $page?>'">
```

Using jQuery, you could poll a script which responds with new comments, something like this:

```
function doPoll(){
    $.post('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
        alert(data);  // process results here
        setTimeout(doPoll,5000);
    });
}
```

The best option however for auto loading fresh comments is to use something like **NodeJs**. This involves running node on your server, and some js on the page. Rather than the js polling the script, the node server notifies the client, so it's the other way around. I can't give an example of that as I haven't used it, but I'm sure it isn't hard to find examples online.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you delboy1978uk and @samuel. I know I cant use node as Siteground does not support it - This is seeming a little over my head, I'll keep working though :) My siteground server supports Ajax - do I need to install it or just reference it with .ajax?

Comment: AJAX is just the concept. Javascript has `fetch()` and `XMLHttpRequest()` built in. No need to set anything up.